# Theme Unit testing not importing on MAMP server - Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Tags: posts

I imported the [theme unit xml file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test)  with the wordpress importer. But all of the data is imported as pages. I am following an online tutorial to build a wordpress framework and I believe the data should be imported as posts.

When I get to the importer screen I see the following error messages:

```
 Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class WXR_Parser_Regex in C:\MAMP\htdocs\framework\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-importer\parsers.php on line 408

 Strict Standards: Declaration of WP_Import::bump_request_timeout() should be compatible with WP_Importer::bump_request_timeout($val) in C:\MAMP\htdocs\framework\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-importer\wordpress-importer.php on line 38
```

But I can proceed with the import. I can choose to import authors or to assign a existing author and I can choose to import/download attachments (wich I did).

This is not the first time I tried so in the next screen I get a list of imported media and pages wich already exist:

> Pagina “About The Tests” bestaat al.
>
> Media “dsc20050813_115856_52” bestaat al.

I also get a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in `C:\MAMP\htdocs\framework\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1513`
```

And two warnings:

```
Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (1) in C:\MAMP\htdocs\framework\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3282

Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (1) in C:\MAMP\htdocs\framework\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3282
```

I get a bunch of pages and media but no posts.

How should I fix this so I can import all the content?

Comment: That import does contain pages as well as posts, have you verified everything that is in the list of things the import contains is in your site? And that you have everything selected on the importer, not just pages?

Comment: Hi, did you see the sentence "All Done" after you upload the xml file?

Comment: I edited the question!

Comment: I am developing on my local machine with MAMP, so not sure that internet line would help. I tried with a clean instal, but i get the same result. I guess it has to do with the speed of my MAMP server?

Answer (score 0):

I added the line set_time_limit(600); to my php.ini file in MAMP. In order to do this I had to copy the php.ini file from MAMP/conf/php5.6.3 and paste it in MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.3.